# Make active page link hold solid bg color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want the active link on the page to have a solid bg color. I think i need jQuery to do this. I tried this code, but it doesn't work..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#navigation").each(function(){
    if($(this).attr('href') == document.URL){
        $(this).css("background-Color", "#e9fd99");
    }
});
});
</script>
```

See my picture for clarification:

[image]

As you can see -- depending on which page you're on the link will a solid BG color that stays static..

-----------------------UPDATE-------------------------

HTML code:

```
<div id="navigation">
<div class="sb_pos">
<ul id="red" class="treeview-red">

<li class="open">
    <span class="tree_titles">About</span>
    <ul>


        <li><span><a href="?page=about_getting_started">Getting Started</a></span></li>
        <li><span><a href="?page=about_recruiting_process">Recruiting Process</a></span></li>
        <li><span><a href="?page=about_responsibility">Responsibility</a></span></li>
        <li><span><a href="?page=about_opportunity">Opportunity</a></span></li>
```

Comment: Thank you all for the suggestions. I will try each and comment back tomorrow as appropriate. Thanks again for the support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with only css if you want. Give the body of each page a unique id, for example about, contact, tags, etc. Then give each link a unique id, aboutlink, contactlink, tagslink, etc.

Then in your css, write the style:

```
body#about a#aboutlink,
body#contact a#contactlink,
body#tags a#tagslink {
    background-color: #e9fd99;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant this

```
         $("#navigation").each(function(){
```

instead of this

```
        $("navigation").each(function(){
```

if you are selecting by id , use #navigation , if the class name is navigation use .navigation

Try this

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function(){
             $(".newclass > li").each(function(){
                 if($(this).attr('href') == document.URL){
                    $(this).css("background-Color", "#e9fd99");
                 }
             });
        });
   </script>
```

add this

```
     <ul class="newclass">
    <li><span><a href="?page=about_getting_started">Getting Started</a></span></li>
    <li><span><a href="?page=about_recruiting_process">Recruiting Process</a></span>   </li>
    <li><span><a href="?page=about_responsibility">Responsibility</a></span></li>
    <li><span><a href="?page=about_opportunity">Opportunity</a></span></li>
```

It has to be selecting the direct child of the parent.

Comment: does each link have the id of navigation? or is that the parent?

Comment: That is the `parent` and it is an `id`

Comment: then you are checking for each parent , that won't work , what are the child element type h1, a, ect.

Comment: the links are nested in `ul` and then `li`

Comment: That didn't work -> also these links are in a PHP include file, though I don't think that would make a difference...

Comment: you need to ".addClass("active") or "selected" to your function then style the class through css

Comment: @JordyVialoux I don't know how to do that.. Can you help me please? `$(this).addClass(".activeItem");` and made css class .activeItem -> --- corrected- still no dice on either solution.. @Scott tried new code.. no dice..

Comment: Sure @FabioAnselmo will give you a jsfiddle link shortly

Comment: Also @FabioAnselmo I'm not positive  == document.URL) will work because document.URL might compare to the entire URL

Comment: @ScottSelby it isn't comparing the entire `URL` I just tested for that and it still didn't work.. So that's surely not the issue..

Answer (score 0):

Try this, uncomment console.log and check if href is equals of you need

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $("#navigation").each(function(){
            //console.log($(this).attr('href'));
            //console.log(window.location.search);
            if($(this).attr('href') == window.location.search){
                $(this).css("background-Color", "#e9fd99");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a few problems with your JavaScript. First, the jQuery "each" function doesn't iterate over the children of a selected element, it iterates over all instances of a selected element. See http://api.jquery.com/each/ for some examples of this function in use. So instead of

```
$("#navigation").each(function(){
    ...
});
```

if you want to iterate over the "li" elements, you should use

```
 $("#navigation li").each(function(){
    ...
});
```

or some more specific selector that selects li elements (it could also be `$(".open li")` based on the HTML you provided). Note that you can't use the ">" selector because that specifies a direct  child, and the `li` is not a direct child of the `div`.

Second, once you select the `li`, you can't refer to `(this).attr('href')` because `this` refers to the `li`, which doesn't have an `href` attribute. You'll need to select the `a` element underneath the selected `li` with either `$("a", this)` or `$(this).find("a")`.

Finally, `document.URL` returns the entire URL of the current document, http:// and all, but you're comparing it to the `href` property of the link, which is just the relative path `?page=about_getting_started`. This will never be equal even if you're looking at the correct link. You'll want to use `window.location.pathname` instead, since this will return the current relative path.

Answer (score 0):

This is a VERY SIMPLE solution: you can use PHP to grab from the URL the value you wish and inserting the grabbed value at a jQuery code like:

```
$('.#').addClass('active');
```

Where "#" is the value grabbed from the URL. For example:

```
<?php

echo '<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){';
if(intval($_GET['page']) > 0) {
    $from_url = intval($_GET['page']);
    } else {
        if(isset($_GET['page'])) {
        $from_url = $_GET['page'];
        } else {
        $from_url = 'index';
        }
    }
echo '
    $(\'' . $from_url . '\').addClass(\'active\');
    });
</script>';

?>
```

Also explained [here](http://eduardomarques.com/snippets/jquery-active-links/).